# Is there a way to display the value instead of (?) using query builder in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent Query Builder to produce raw sql for me. My goal is to return a sql query like this

```
select * from accounts where id = '120'
```

now i tried

```
$query = \App\Account::query();
$query = $query->where('id', 120);
dd($query->toSql());
```

Output:

```
select * from `accounts` where `id` = ?
```

is there a way to display the value instead of (?) because this is not a valid query on the third party API that i'm using.
I'm expecting to produce a query on my first example that i give.

Note: I'm not querying on my database, i will use that raw query to pass on the 3rd party API. All i want is to produce only a raw sql. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this, maybe it can help to someone that has same problem with me.

You can check this link: https://gist.github.com/JesseObrien/7418983

```
public function getSql() 
{
    $builder = $this->getBuilder(); 
    $sql = $builder->toSql();
    foreach($builder->getBindings() as $binding)
    {
      $value = is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'".$binding."'";
      $sql = preg_replace('/\?/', $value, $sql, 1);
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can print the parameters value by using `getBindings()`

```
print_r( $query->getBindings() );
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => instructor
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: HI @Qazi, how will i achive this?
select * from accounts where id = '120'

Comment: @Juan as per my R&D you cannot achieve parameter value instead ?, All you get parameter list.

Comment: i mean is there an alternative for this?

Comment: the only way available which I shared with you in my answer.